# MvcOptions.Conventions using .NET Core 3.x

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core 3.x, `UseEndpoints` replaced the `UseMvc` application builder configuration in `Startup.Configure`, as suggested by the ASP.NET Core migration guide:

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
  });
```

In our app, we used the `MvcOptions.Conventions`property to add custom `IModelController` conventions during startup:

```
  app.UseMvc(options => options.Conventions.Add(...))
```

I could not find any documentation on how to add the conventions in ASP.NET Core 3.x. Is the feature still supported?

Comment: Not sure about this but it is worth a try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addmvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_MvcServiceCollectionExtensions_AddMvc_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_MvcOptions__

Comment: Thank you, but AddMvc ist not supported when using Endpoint Routing.